# Detect Pdf reader in MsIE

Tags: internet-explorer, detection, pdf-viewer

I use an IFrame to view a Pdf document when a link within that IFrame is clicked. However, on machines without the reader, the link will prompt for download. Is there a way, that the same link can prompt the user to download a reader when it detects no reader instead? I thought I have seen this somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: You *might* also have to take into account the fact that many users (myself included) disable browser integration with their PDF reader.

Comment: In MsIE 7, how would one choose to disable the browser integration with a PDF reader?

Comment: +1 for disabling annoying in-browser pdf readers!

Comment: If you want to disable it, assuming you are using adobe reader, it's in the adobe reader preferences. Note that some browsers also offer the ability to disable this functionality, not sure if IE offers this or not though.

Comment: Please don't do this.  Let the user decide what to open PDFs in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me in IE:

```
<script>
var p;
try {
p = new ActiveXObject('AcroExch.Document');
}
catch (e) {
// active x object could not be created
document.write('doesnt look like the PDF plugin is installed...');
}
if (p) {
    document.write('does look like the pdf plugin is installed!');
}
</script>
```

[Found it here.](http://www.oreillynet.com/cs/user/view/cs_msg/6639) ..but modified to remove the "endif"

Comment: However crude with much activeX flaggings with MsIE, this seemed to be the working one.

Comment: is there any cross browser jquery detection?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question had been answered already, but I recently had to build a function that detects PDF plug-in presence across different browsers. This is what I got. Hopefully if helps.

```
function hasPdfPlugin() {   
//detect in mimeTypes array
if (navigator.mimeTypes != null && navigator.mimeTypes.length > 0) {        
    for (i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; i++) {
        var mtype = navigator.mimeTypes[i];
        if(mtype.type == "application/pdf" && mtype.enabledPlugin)
            return true;
    }
}

//detect in plugins array
if (navigator.plugins != null && navigator.plugins.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) {
        var plugin = navigator.plugins[i];
        if (plugin.name.indexOf("Adobe Acrobat") > -1
                || plugin.name.indexOf("Adobe Reader") > -1) {
            return true;
        }

    }
} 
// detect IE plugin
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // check for presence of newer object       
    try {
        var oAcro7 = new ActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF.1');
        if (oAcro7) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }

    // iterate through version and attempt to create object 
    for (x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
        try {
            var oAcro = eval("new ActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl." + x + "');");
            if (oAcro) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }

    // check if you can create a generic acrobat document
    try {
        var p = new ActiveXObject('AcroExch.Document');
        if (p) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }

}

// Can't detect in all other cases
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here are a few scripts](http://dithered.chadlindstrom.ca/javascript/acrobat.html) that help detect the presence of Acrobat.

Comment: This appear as if it is the most comprehensive approach, however, I am still struggling to make it work. Any spoon feeding would be most appreciated. I am interested in the http://dithered.chadlindstrom.ca/javascript/acrobat_redirect/index.html

Comment: Could you provide some information on how this works? I feel like just providing a link without explanation is better than nothing, but still leaves something to be desired.

Comment: I've implemented the scripts on a couple of sites with no problems. And I do not see the need to replicate information from the site here when all relevant details are available on the site.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, can you do something like:

```
var adobePdfObject = new ActiveXObject("theAdobePdfCOMObject");
```

and then either catch a failure error or the return value of adobePdfObject?